# SoundCloud widget doubles when visiting the main site (possible https issue)

Tags: javascript, https, soundcloud

I'm integrating the SoundCloud player widget into a website. I would expect that when the user clicks the "view track" link next to a song in the playlist the player would stop. It does not do this, and the player on SoundCloud's website begins playing over the one on my website.

The only hint I have is this message in my console

```
 Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "https://w.soundcloud.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://localhost".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "https", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "http". Protocols must match.
```

Is it possible that my lack of https is causing some issue here?

**Edit**

I've tried removing all of my other JavaScript and the problem persists. In fact it even happens in a completely blank html file with nothing but the iframe.
This is the minimal code that produces the problem for me (minus the API token).

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="//w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/playlists/bleh%3Fsecret_token%3Ds-blah&amp;show_comments=true&amp;color=ff0000&amp;theme_color=91d0d6&amp;show_artwork=false&amp;auto_play=false"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

**Edit 2**

[Here's a jsbin](http://jsbin.com/pehuwune/1/edit?html,output) that produces the behavior for me. It only seems to happen if I don't already have SoundCloud open in another tab.

Answer (score 2):

Does it happen only on your local machine?
Could you please provide us with an isolated test case on jsbin.com or something like that?

I have tried to reproduce it on both localhost and jsbin and no errors were thrown.

Anyway, I guess it's related to the limitation a browser puts on `window.postMessage` method in order to prevent XSS attacks.

We use `window.postMessage` in Widget API (for setting up a communication between widget iframe and parent page) and I've just added a fix to make this part of code more defensive so that no messages are being sent to parent window if we cant get access to it.

It'll be live by the end of today.

Comment: It's happening online as well. I'll see if I can put together something on jsbin that exhibits the same behavior.

Comment: Also I've only been able to reproduce it in firefox and chrome. For some reason safari isn't affected.